# How to point the netlify preview link to deployed branch

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms

When I make changes to a page and save the changes. It deploys a preview branch via netlify with (https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/deploy-previews/).

However when I click on the netlify preview button, it just links to a default url like: `https://blablala.netlify.app`. And not to the preview branch like: `https://deploy-preview-26--blablala.netlify.app`

[image: Preview link]

How do I get the preview button to link to my deploy preview?

Thanks!